# How to define type with UseState and Firebase snapshot when you want to .map the data?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Relevant Code:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

 useEffect(
    () =>
      onSnapshot(
        query(collection(db, "posts"), orderBy("timestamp", "desc")),
        (snapshot) => {
          setPosts(snapshot.docs);
        }
      ),
    [db]
  );

 return (
 <div>
   {posts.map((post) => (
      <Post key={post.id} id={post.id} post={post.data()} />
    ))}
 </div>
)
```

The above code does run fine locally, but for **deployment** it seems like UseState being [] or undefined or null with .map is throwing an error.

Errors I've gotten so far:

> 1: Type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.

So I tried altering UseState and snapshot as any, then we get error 2

> 2: Type error: Parameter 'post' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Then, I tried using String[] but that didn't work either

Then, I tried moving .map up (snapshot.docs.map) to get error 3

> 3: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First, you can create an interface for your `Post` document. For example,

```
interface IPost {
  id: string
  title: string
  // other fields
}
```

Then you can use it with `useState` to define the type:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState<IPost>([]);
```

Additionally, you can set the data itself in state instead of the `QueryDocumentSnapshot` array:

```
setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((d) => ({ id: d.id, ...d.data() })) as IPost[])
```

```
return (
 <div>
   {posts.map((post) => (
      <Post key={post.id} id={post.id} post={post} />
    ))}
 </div>
)
```